# Writing List items to text file c#

Tags: c#, list, listbox, text-files, save-as

I am trying to get a `List` to save into a text file and am running into a problem.
It will save into the text file but not all the information as needed but only the information that actually shows in the `ListBox`. Suggestions?

```
namespace Employee_Form
{
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    FileStream output;
    StreamReader fileReader;
    //StreamWriter fileWriter;
    List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();


    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFile();
    }

    private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveAs();
    }

    private void addNewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PropertiesOpen();
    }

    private void PropertiesOpen()
    {

        //creates an instance of the Properties Form
        frmProperties myform = new frmProperties();
        DialogResult result = myform.ShowDialog();
    }


    //Opens a file chosen by a user and places information into the listbox
    private void OpenFile()
    {

        OpenFileDialog fileChooser = new OpenFileDialog();

        fileChooser.Title = "Pick a file";
        fileChooser.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt) | *.txt";

        DialogResult result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();

        //
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            //do nothing
            return;
        }

        string strFileName = fileChooser.FileName;

        try
        {
            //open the file for read access
            output = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            fileReader = new StreamReader(output);

            //variables to hold read record
            string strInputLine;
            string[] fields;

            //loop to get records and break into fields
            while (fileReader.EndOfStream != true)
            {
                //read record
                strInputLine = fileReader.ReadLine();

                //split the records when read
                fields = strInputLine.Split(',');

                //add records to the list box 
                employeeList.Add(new Employee(fields[1], fields[0], fields[2], 
                                     Convert.ToDouble(fields[3])));

            }
            lstRecords.DataSource = employeeList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //closes fileReader and output to save Resources
            fileReader.Close();
            output.Close();
        }
    }

    public void SaveAs()
    {
        //create a file dialog
        SaveFileDialog fileChooser = new SaveFileDialog();
        fileChooser.Title = "Choose A Save Location";
        fileChooser.Filter = "Text Files (*txt)|*.txt";

        //open the dialog and get a result
        DialogResult result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();

        //checks if user clicks cancel
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }

        //get the file name from the dialog
        string strFileName = fileChooser.FileName;
        try
        {
            //open the new file for write access
            StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(strFileName);

            foreach (var item in employeeList)
            {
                SaveFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
            SaveFile.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            //close resources
            //fileWriter.Close();
            output.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, I am new to this. There are two forms and the second one is for editing/adding new employees. only need to show the first and last name in the ListBox. Here is my Employee class also:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string EmpType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double Salary
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, string empType, double salary)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        EmpType = empType;
        Salary = salary;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}", LastName, FirstName);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `employeeList`? and what is `item`?

Comment: Where is this additional information coming from? it acts like your code is doing just what you are asking, saving the contents of your List.

Comment: we will need more data than that. What type is var item? what type is employeeList? my first clue would be that item.ToString() only returns a specific property of @item type@ instead of all of them... you would need to override the item.ToString() method to return more.

Comment: is there a reason that you are using a `List<dynamic>` instead of a `List<Employee>` ?

Comment: Actually no, that was a typo. I do have List<Employee> here now.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `SaveFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());`, you're writing the result of the `ToString()` method of `Employee`:

```
return string.Format("{0}, {1}", LastName, FirstName);
```

This is the same method called by the `ListBox` to display the object in the list. So the behavior you're seeing is exactly what one would expect.

If you want to see something different, try something like this:

```
SaveFile.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", item.LastName, item.FirstName, item.EmpType, item.Salary));
```

Use whatever properties and formatting you want in your file.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking at that line trying to figure out if it was my culprit. It works perfectly now!